# Can all TV connection sockets in Germany be used for Internet?

Tags: networking, internet, tv

I'm living in Munich (Germany) and my girlfriend wants to have internet in her room. There are multiple providers which offer internet through TV cable, but there is no information on how exactly this works. Are the TV jacks all standardized or are there multiple types? Are they all internally connected in the same way so that you can be certain that you will be able to use it for internet?

We see the jacks (2) and (3). I think (1) is for satellite, (2) is for TV and (3) is for radio.

[image]

Comment: Saying all would be a risk as there are 5% which don't, your best option is to call the provider or to just try. The place where I am even the radio plug can be used. 1 and 2 should work. Jack 1 goes to the router.

Comment: But we don't have (1). We only have (2) and (3). Could that possibly still work?

Comment: Which details are required for this question?

Comment: Jack 2 or Jack 3 has to go to the router. You can ask your provider will he supply the internet through jacks 2 and 3, then you need a cable that will fit both ends. You might need to make the cable yourself, by buying a coax cable and changing the end to fit the router and this jack.